# The physical meaning of the negative sign of the specific orbital energy for elliptic orbit

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

I know that when the specific orbital energy of a body is equal to or smaller than 0, the body will be gravitationally bounded to the stars/planets it is orbiting around. However, I do not fully understand the physical meaning of total energy being negative.

Does it mean that the magnitude of the potential energy is larger than that of the kinetic energy so that the body does not have enough KE to "overcome" the potential energy? And the negative sign in front of the specific orbital energy just tells us the relationship between KE and PE, i.e. an indicator of which one is larger in magnitude?

Comment: It has to be smaller than 0. If it's exactly zero, the body has escape velocity and a [parabolic trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_trajectory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's mostly correct. Potential energy is always negatively signed for attractive forces and positively signed for repulsive forces because of the convention of putting the zero at infinite distance. Specific orbital energy is the sum of kinetic energy (always positive) and gravitational potential energy (always negative).